# Why do partial and full C++ template specializations, that look almost the same, produce different results?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-specialization, template-instantiation

I haven't written many C++ templates till recently, but I'm trying to take a deep dive into them. Fixing one developer's code I managed to produce some compiler behavior that I can't explain. Here is the simplified program. ( When I try to simplify more, I lose that "strange" behavior). Let's think of some class Depender, which is a parameter of template struct Dependency. `Depender` can depend on the List of `Dependee`s. I have some macros that can produce specializations of the `Dependency` template. Dots in the following code block stand for the possible macro expansion. I have a **forward-declared** MainDependee before dots, and MainDependee's **definition** after dots.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct IsCompleteType : std::false_type
{};

template <typename T>
struct IsCompleteType<T, std::enable_if_t<( sizeof( T ) > 0 )>> : std::true_type
{};

template<template<typename...> class List, typename Dependee>
struct DependencyInternal
{
    using Type = std::conditional_t<IsCompleteType<Dependee>::value, Dependee, Dependee>;
};

template<typename... Ts> class StubList;

class MainDependee;  // forward declaration
class MainDepender
{};

template<template<typename...> class List, typename Depender>
struct Dependency;

....... //here is the specialization

class MainDependee {};
int main()
{
   Dependency<StubList, MainDepender> a;
}
```

When the dots are replaced with

```
template<template<typename... Us> class List>
struct Dependency<List, MainDepender>
{
    using Type = typename DependencyInternal<List, MainDependee>::Type;
};
```

then in `main` I get `IsCompleteType<MainDependee>::value == true`.

But when the dots are replaced with

```
template<>
struct Dependency<StubList, MainDepender>
{
    using Type = typename DependencyInternal<StubList, MainDependee>::Type;
};
```

then `IsCompleteType<MainDependee>::value == false`.

Please tell me, what rule describes the difference between these options?

[Try the code yourself](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=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&insightsOptions=cpp20&std=cpp20&rev=1.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explicit (full) specialization is not itself a templated entity and all name lookup etc., as well as ODR, is done for it as if it wasn't a template. `MainDependee` is not complete at the point you wrote it and therefore `IsCompleteType<MainDependee>` is inherited from `std::false_type` at this point.

A partial specialization is itself a templated entity and will follow the rules for templates. In particular a definition will be instantiated from the partial specialization only when and where an instantiation is required. In this case the instantiation for `Dependency<StubList, MainDepender>` has its point of instantiation directly before `main` where `MainDependee` is complete. Only there `Type` is computed (because the right-hand side is dependent on the template parameter) and `IsCompleteType<MainDependee>` instantiated, so that it will be inherited from `std::true_type`.

Note that class template specializations are instantiated only once per translation unit. If you use `Dependency<StubList, MainDepender>::value` multiple times in a translation unit, it will always result in the same value, the one which would be correct at the first point from where instantiation is required.

Furthermore, if `Dependency<StubList, MainDepender>::value` or `IsCompleteType<MainDependee>` would have different values in different translation units because of different relative placement of `MainDependee`, your program will be IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required), effectively meaning it will have undefined behavior.

It is not possible to use a type trait like this to safely check whether a type is complete. For the same reason there is no such trait in the standard library.

Comment: [Please check this code](https://cppinsights.io/s/c6830fb0).
here the specialization is also partial but the result is `false`. why so?
I removed the underlying DependencyInternal and put its body right into Dependency's partial spec

Comment: @soad Now you use `IsCompleteType<MainDependee>` directly in the partial specialization without it being dependent on a template parameter. If the meaning of a non-dependent construct directly after the definition of a template is different than it would be at a point of instantiation, then the program is also IFNDR.

Comment: OK, then it's all about dependent names and postponed binding. Now it's clear for me, thank you. I guess, using incomplete types in templates specializations is always a bad and error-prone option?

Comment: @soad Using incomplete types is generally fine. The issue here is specifically that you have behavior that conditionally gives different results based on completeness, i.e. the `std::enable_if_t<( sizeof( T ) > 0 )>`. You can use incomplete types with templates that don't need the type to be complete (i.e. your use of `MainDepender`) or if e.g. only member function bodies require completeness and completeness can be delayed until they are used (e.g. `std::vector` with an incomplete type). In most cases using an incomplete type where a complete one is required also just errors (safely).